# Использование dll в зависимости от разрядности системы

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Получил заказ написать программу которая будет принимать пакеты по CAN Bus. Я программу написал, код не прошу, но, появилась одна из проблем, а именно: программа не работает на х86 машине, если она компилировалась на х64-й.

Вот вопрос: могу ли я скомпилировать программу таким образом, чтобы я мог использовать её на системе х64 и х86 разрядностей? А также в зависимости от разряда системы она подтягивала свою DLL.

DLL я использую уже готовые: PISOCAN_NET.dll - х86, а PISOCAN_х64.dll - х64

Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Как вариант: сделать отдельный лаунчер x86 который будет запускать один из двух исполняемых файлов которые с свою очередь подтягивают свои dll.

Comment: AnyCPU + [conditional reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio)?

Comment: @andreycha В поле ответа надо было сразу писать.

Comment: @AK лень было расписывать.